# How to make g_printer (USB-gadget printer) work in Raspberian Pi

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, raspbian, usb-device

I'm trying to use gadget mode on a Raspberry Pi Zero W and the `g_printer` device to emulate a printer so I can capture data, process it, and send it to some APIs over wi-fi. I've set up the board using the instructions at https://gist.github.com/gbaman/50b6cca61dd1c3f88f41. Using the `g_ether` device the board will show up as a network device to my Macbook. However, if I edit the `/etc/modules` to contain `g_printer` rather than `g_ether` (only one, and reboot) the board does not show up as a printer available to the Macbook.

modinfo returns:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ modinfo g_printer
filename:       /lib/modules/4.9.65+/kernel/drivers/usb/gadget/legacy/g_printer.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Craig Nadler
description:    Printer Gadget
srcversion:     2F1D50E570B8D48FA4C2DD9
depends:        libcomposite,udc-core
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.9.65+ mod_unload modversions ARMv6 p2v8 
parm:           idVendor:USB Vendor ID (ushort)
parm:           idProduct:USB Product ID (ushort)
parm:           bcdDevice:USB Device version (BCD) (ushort)
parm:           iSerialNumber:SerialNumber string (charp)
parm:           iManufacturer:USB Manufacturer string (charp)
parm:           iProduct:USB Product string (charp)
parm:           iSerialNum:1 (charp)
parm:           iPNPstring:MFG:linux;MDL:g_printer;CLS:PRINTER;SN:1; (charp)
parm:           qlen:uint
```

so it looks to be loaded. What else is needed for the board to show up as a printer?

Comment: Cross posted on [Raspberry Pi Forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=198907)

Answer (score 3):

The `g_printer` module can be added to the `cmdline.txt` in the same way as the `g_ether` module.

Edit the cmdline.txt file and add this directly after `rootwait`

```
modules-load=dwc2,g_printer
```

Edit the config.txt file and add this directly after the last line in the file:

```
dtoverlay=dwc2
```

When the Raspberry Pi boots with the USB cable plugged into a GNU/Linux system, you'll receive something like in your system messages:

```
dmesg
```

---

```
[40692.579011] usb 2-1.4.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=a4a8
[40692.579014] usb 2-1.4.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[40692.579016] usb 2-1.4.3: Product: Printer Gadget
[40692.579018] usb 2-1.4.3: Manufacturer: Linux 4.9.59+ with 20980000.usb
[40692.579020] usb 2-1.4.3: SerialNumber: 1
[40692.600820] usblp 2-1.4.3:1.0: usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 18 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x0525 pid 0xA4A8
[40692.600851] usbcore: registered new interface driver usblp
```

I don't have a MacOSx machine handy to test, but the Raspberry Pi should be seen as a printer device.

**On the seeing which modules are loaded**

`modinfo` doesn't show which modules are running.  `lsmod` will show all loaded modules.

Comment: Thanks for the additional debug info. The link I posted did have the install correct. I found the problem was that the printer had to be manually installed in OSX by clicking the `+` button rather than it showing up on its own. Now that it is there as linux_g_printer, however, I only get garbage when I send data from my Macbook with `lp -d linux_g_printer some_text_file.txt` and listen on the RPi as `sudo cat /dev/g_printer0` . Not quite success yet.

Comment: @GeorgeShaw : The incoming data is most likely binary try: `strings /dev/g_printer0`

Comment: The file I'm sending is a readme text file so it should be text except for newlines. Running `strings` on the file on the Macbook displays the lines of the file. Running it on the RPi displays nothing. It looks like the data arriving at the `g_printer0` is being corrupted (or modified) so mostly non-printable data (binary) is being returned, and thus no output from `strings`. It's like a classical serial port baud rate problem, but that should not apply here.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, to use the `g_printer` you have to use the module parameters `vendorID`, `productID` and `iPNPstring`. Either take these from your own printer or find them [here](http://www.openprinting.org/foomatic-db/db/source/printer/). I suggest to only add

```
dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=peripheral
```

to the end of `config.txt`. You will load the `g_printer` module after the boot later.

Craig W. Nadler posted a [good example code](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget_printer.rst) on how to use the `/dev/g_printer device` descriptor.

I created a [repository](https://github.com/Raspberryy/Emulated_USB_Printer) for a little more detailed explanation if you want to learn more about what exactly you will need to do to use the Raspberry Pi Zero as a printer.